# get the value of the last array with unknown number id

Tags: javascript, json, fetch, number-formatting

I'd like to calculate a price change for different time periods with the following code:

```
     var lastId = data.prices.length;
     var numberOf = Number(lastId);     
     document.getElementById('ideir').innerHTML = data.prices[numberOf][1] - data.prices[0][1];
```

data.prices.length on its own gives something like 274 - a number. When I try to use it as a number iD for a json fetched data it stops working. I tried to convert it to a number just in case, but first of all it already is a number, and secondly it's also not working as a number iD.
The data.prices[0][1] on its own gives the correct json value - the first price from the fetched time period.

What should I do to get the value of the last available from the fetched JSON data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array in javascript start from `0` so the last element would have the index of `length - 1`. The third line should look like this:

```
document.getElementById('ideir').innerHTML = data.prices[numberOf-1][1] - data.prices[0][1];
```